# Error with rfModel.toDebugString

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark with Spark 2.2 and Python 2.7.11 and I am trying to extract rules from the decision trees of a random forest classifier using the `.toDebugString` Method.

I had success with it but since the update from 2.1 to 2.2, Spark crashes after I use this command and I get this error:

Full error:

```
rfModel.toDebugString
```

> ----------------------------------------u'RandomForestClassificationModel (uid=RandomForestClassifier_4e99b85432585e2e32a2) with 30 trees\n  Tr'
>       Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 42374)
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
>           self.process_request(request, client_address)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
>           self.finish_request(request, client_address)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>           self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in **init**
>           self.handle()
>         File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/accumulators.py",
>   line 235, in handle
>           num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
>         File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 577, in read_int
>       ----------------------------------------
>           raise EOFError
>       EOFError

If I run the command again after this error I get:

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o1129.toString

My code is fairly straightforward and this confuses me very much.

```
#Get random forest from pipeline 
rfModel = model.stages[1]

rfModel.toDebugString
```

I know rfModel is a randomForestClassifier object. Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: you need to post more of the error message

Comment: Found a solution. Python version was creating the problem. Will recreate the error and update with log for future users.

Comment: _"/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2"_ Are you using CDH? What's the version of CDH?

Comment: Yes i am, Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.11.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was the python version. By using python3+ with spark 2.2 i managed to work .toDebugString method without a problem. I will update with full error log for anyone seeing this in the future.